# facial recognition using unity 3D. How to fix this code in C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The piece of code keeps going into the else condition without performing the first part of IF statement.

```
public void OnSaveButtonClick ()
{
    Debug.Log ("User clicked [Save] button.");

    string saveDirectoryPath = Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, saveDirectoryName);

    if (model != null)
    {
        // Clean up old files.
        if (Directory.Exists (saveDirectoryPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo (saveDirectoryPath);
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                if ((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly) 
                {
                    fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                }
            }
            if ((directoryInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                directoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory;
            }
            directoryInfo.Delete (true);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory (saveDirectoryPath);

        // save the train data.
        model.write (Path.Combine (saveDirectoryPath, "traindata.yml"));

        // save the preprocessedfaces.
        #if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
        string format = "jpg";
        MatOfInt compressionParams = new MatOfInt(Imgcodecs.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100);
        #else
        string format = "png";
        MatOfInt compressionParams = new MatOfInt (Imgcodecs.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0);
        #endif
        for (int i = 0; i < m_numPersons; ++i)
        {
            Imgcodecs.imwrite (Path.Combine (saveDirectoryPath, "preprocessedface" + i + "." + format), preprocessedFaces [m_latestFaces [i]], compressionParams);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("save failure. train data does not exist.");
    }
}
```

> save failure. train data does not exist.
>   
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   
> RealTimeFaceRecognitionExample.WebCamTextureRealTimeFaceRecognitionExample:OnSaveButtonClick() (at Assets/RealTimeFaceRecognitionExample/WebCamTextureRealTimeFaceRecognitionExample/WebCamTextureRealTimeFaceRecognitionExample.cs:541)
>   
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Comment: Where is `model` set?

Answer (score 1):

After scanning the image or person you have to click anywhere in the image or face of the person being scanned to train the data before saving.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with the code appears to be an incomplete `if` statement. There is an `if` statement on line 12 that has a condition, but the code block that follows is incomplete.

To fix this, you can either complete the `if` statement by adding a closing brace and else block to handle the case where the directory doesn't exist, or you can remove the `if` statement entirely and simply create a new directory. Here's an example of how you can complete the `if` statement to properly handle the case where the directory exists:

```
public void OnSaveButtonClick()
{
    Debug.Log("User clicked [Save] button.");

    string saveDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, saveDirectoryName);

    if (model != null)
    {
        // Clean up old files.
        if (Directory.Exists(saveDirectoryPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(saveDirectoryPath);
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                if ((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
                {
                    fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                }
            }
            
            // Close the if statement by adding this block 
            if ((directoryInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                directoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            }
        }
        
        // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        if (!Directory.Exists(saveDirectoryPath)){
            Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDirectoryPath);
        }

        // Save the data
        string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectoryPath, saveFileName);
        model.Save(saveFilePath);
    }
}
```

This way, the code is able to handle both cases where the directory exists and where it doesn't exist. If it exists, the code will clean up the old files and set the directory attributes to normal. If it doesn't exist, the code will simply create a new directory and save the data.